# How can I declare IQueryable<T> when T is unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, iqueryable

I'm creating a generic method to call a repository load method to retrieve database records from a table defined by class `T` where `T` is unknown until run time.

Additionally, the code below makes use of the known type BLL.Entities.Unit but I need to change this to use the modelType shown in the GetData method.  I couldn't figure out how to format the param2 parameter without using the Unit directly.

Here's the code in my method:

```
public JsonResult GetData(string modelTypeString)
{            
    Type modelType = Type.GetType(modelTypeString);
    MethodInfo generic = typeof(Repository).GetMethod("Load");
    MethodInfo genericLoad = generic.MakeGenericMethod(modelType);

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<BLL.Entities.Unit, object>>[] param2 = 
        new System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<BLL.Entities.Unit, object>>[1];
    var returnObjects = genericLoad.Invoke(Repository, param2);
}
```

And here is the Repository Load method:

```
public IQueryable<T> Load<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> query = entities.Set<T>();
    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```

This code compiles and executes, but I can't do any queryable actions on the `returnObjects`.  I need to do something like:

```
returnObjects.Select(u => new UnitViewModel
{
    Id = u.Id,
    Name = u.Name,
    Description = u.Description,
    DDLocationId = u.LocationId
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Does your `T` implement an interface? How do you know it will have Id, Name, Description and LocationId?

Comment: You've already negated the power of generics by calling it with reflection.  Now you're stuck with continuing to use reflection, doing an unsafe cast, or using `dynamic`.  Generics and reflection do not mix well.

Comment: Why don't you just make `GetData` generic too so you don't have to use reflection? At some point you're going to have to know the compile-time type.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the expression that you pass in. It seems to me that you are using `BLL.Entities.Unit` instead of the runtime type (`modelType`).

Comment: @YacoubMassad you're right.  My apologies for the confusion.  The code above is in a bit of a state of flux.  The requirement is to get to use the modelType in param2.  I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @nvoigt T does not implement an interface.  In debugging I was using a specific type.  Just trying to get to the next step.

Comment: @DStanley I'm starting to see what you mean re: reflection & generics not mixing well.  I was hoping there was a way to make it work.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx
I have implemented this very successfully, in my code, with some minor modifications for DateTime types.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with one line of code:

```
returnObjects.GetEnumerator();
```

This forces a retrieval of data from the database.  After that it's just a matter of using additional reflection code to get at the individual field properties.

Answer (score 0):

Using your repository and map all the objects with AutoMapper is not a solution for you?

What you want is to turn your EntityFramework object into DTO.

I do not know anathing excepted automapper that can allow you to do that without any c# reflexion.

EDIT: And I think your question should be, How to I turn my EF object into DTO.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with AutoMapper.  From what I've seen, you need to know the types at compile time for AutoMapper to work.  In my case, the types are not determined until run time.

Comment: Your Unityobject and UnitViewModel is only know at runtime?
If you are not familiar with AutoMapper you really should have a look to it.
It's all about configuration, and the object will be mapped when needed :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.  Unit and UnitViewModel are hardcoded in my code above as I was debugging this code.  Didn't exactly knock it out of the park with clarity on my first question...